# Is there an Americano with sugar?

Tags: sugar

From what I understand that Americano is a black coffee without sugar or any other sweetener.
So, what if I ask Barista to make me Americano with sugar? 
Is it still an Americano?

Comment: Wouldn’t each customer be free to add sugar to their liking after receiving their coffee drink of choice?

Comment: @Stephie if you pay someone to make you a drink it seems reasonable to ask that they make it to your liking.

Comment: @JJJ interesting. Where I live, *no* cafe or coffee shop would add plain sugar, it’s always up to the customer to do so. The only exception may be flavor syrups, that will be added by the barista, although I have sometimes seen it set out on the tray with sugars, sweetener, milk, creamer etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I look at it, what you add into coffee doesn't change the "type" of coffee.  The act of adding sugar to something doesn't change the type.

- Drip coffee refers to coffee made by dripping water over grinds
- Espresso is water and pressure and fine grind coffee
- Americano refers to coffee made by adding hot water to an espresso
- Cappuccino refers to coffee made by adding steamed milk to an espresso

Adding sugar to any of these drinks doesn't change what type of drink it is.  A coffee snob might say that the "traditional" method is have it black, no sweetener but that doesn't make sense.  I get americano's and sometimes get it with milk and sometimes with sweetener.

Comment: With regular sugar, I agree. Other types of sweetener may change the type of drink. For example chocolate syrup may be used to create a mocha (close to a cappuccino, but with chocolate syrup).